# How to update cursor at setViewValue?

Tags: android, android-listview

Is there any way to manually update cursor's item value from the `setViewValue` code? Currently I just fetch all records again and then `changeCursor` and `notifyDataSetChanged`, but it is very slow:

```
dbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
dbHelper.open();
recordsCursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecords();
startManagingCursor(recordsCursor);

String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_1, DbAdapter.KEY_2};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.background};

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, recordsCursor, from, to);

if (adapter != null) {
    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

            int viewId = view.getId();
            switch(viewId) {
            case R.id.text1:
                final Object item = adapter.getItem(cursor.getPosition());
                ... 
                // some logic is here, so the code below is run only when item is displayed for 5 seconds
                dbHelper.open();
                Boolean result = dbHelper.markRecordAsRead(text); // update the database
                ... 
                // the code below works, but since I read the whole database, it is SLOW
                dbHelper.open();
                recordsCursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecords();
                adapter.changeCursor(recordsCursor);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // is there any way just to update the cursor's item value?
```

Comment: You could use an `AsyncTask` and do the database query in the background..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare, yes, but it will not help me with the read (of course, I could read in the background also, but there is a chance that user will scroll down and then up before I've changed the cursor - so, he/she will see outdated item).